# How can we detect or monitor browser downloads?

Tags: javascript

So, my point is.. I have a file that is in hidden iframe and when window loads, that JS will gets execute and the file will start downloading through browser. Now, there are few things that I want to know here:

1. How does browser estimate the time that is going to take to download the file.
2. How does browser show the amount bytes or kbs of data that has been downloaded.
3. How to detect if the file is downloaded completely?
4. How to detect if there are any network errors in between?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

First you have to know that when you download a file this file is splited into many small packages which than will be downloaded all for themselves and put them back together after the download.

1. The browser knows the size of the file and how long it takes to download 1 package of the file than it can be calculated how long it will take.

   eg. file with 100 byte, 1 package has 1 byte and tooks 0.1 sec to download, than 100*0.1 than it takes 10 sec to download    This is just a sample in real this are much faster
2. It just counts the downloaded parts of the file
3. When the browser starts it knows how many parts that he need so if the downloaded parts same as the known he is complete
4. If it takes too long to retrieve a package or to get a response it throws an error that there is no internet connection.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your quick response but I need some reference to what you are saying. A proper documentation or something where can I chip in and understand completely. Thanks.